# Exception occurred in the TriggeredSendSubscriberHandler

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk, java, triggered-send

I am making request to send a triggered email and the request fails.  I am getting the following response:

```
ID: 13543
Response-Code: 200
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Headers: {Cache-Control=[private, max-age=0], connection=[close], Content-Length=[2989], content-type=[text/xml; charset=utf-8], Date=[Mon, 08 Aug 2016 00:51:23 GMT], Server=[Microsoft-IIS/7.5], X-AspNet-Version=[4.0.30319], X-Powered-By=[ASP.NET]}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<soap:Header>
<wsa:Action>CreateResponse</wsa:Action>
<wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:d8c82238-dec7-4ad0-a6a6-98162ef44085</wsa:MessageID>
<wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:06f96880-b76f-45b6-b909-b1768ce20e60</wsa:RelatesTo>
<wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
<wsse:Security>
  <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-58fc065b-de46-4d08-8462-41518e0e0dd8">
    <wsu:Created>2016-08-08T00:51:24Z</wsu:Created>
    <wsu:Expires>2016-08-08T00:56:24Z</wsu:Expires>
  </wsu:Timestamp>
</wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<CreateResponse xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
  <Results xsi:type="TriggeredSendCreateResult">
    <StatusCode>Error</StatusCode>
    <StatusMessage>Unable to queue Triggered Send request.  There are no valid subscribers.</StatusMessage>
    <OrdinalID>0</OrdinalID>
    <ErrorCode>180008</ErrorCode>
    <NewID>0</NewID>
    <SubscriberFailures>
      <Subscriber>
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ModifiedDate xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <EmailAddress>xxxxxxxx@hotmail.com</EmailAddress>
        <Attributes>
          <Name>restaurantAddress1</Name>
          <Value>333 Ontario Street</Value>
        </Attributes>
        <Attributes>
          <Name>OLOSignupRewardExpiryDate</Name>
          <Value>2017-02-07</Value>
        </Attributes>
        <Attributes>
          <Name>signupRewardExpiryDate</Name>
          <Value>2016-08-22</Value>
        </Attributes>
        <Attributes>
          <Name>restaurantCity</Name>
          <Value>St Catharines</Value>
        </Attributes>
        <Attributes>
          <Name>restaurantPhone</Name>
          <Value>(000) 000-0000</Value>
        </Attributes>
        <Attributes>
          <Name>subscriberKey</Name>
          <Value>0bc572dd-35bd-4952-9787-f3067d3e11d0</Value>
        </Attributes>
        <Attributes>
          <Name>recipientEmail</Name>
          <Value>xxxxxxxx@hotmail.com</Value>
        </Attributes>
        <Attributes>
          <Name>firstName</Name>
          <Value>Philip</Value>
        </Attributes>
        <Attributes>
          <Name>externalId</Name>
          <Value>registration_reward_trigger_prod</Value>
        </Attributes>
        <Attributes>
          <Name>restaurantName</Name>
          <Value>St Catharines</Value>
        </Attributes>
        <Attributes>
          <Name>restaurantProvince</Name>
          <Value>ON</Value>
        </Attributes>
        <SubscriberKey>0bc572dd-35bd-4952-9787-f3067d3e11d0</SubscriberKey>
        <Status>Active</Status>
      </Subscriber>
      <ErrorCode>TriggeredSendSubscriberProcessingError</ErrorCode>
      <ErrorDescription>Exception occurred in the TriggeredSendSubscriberHandler:: ProcessSubscriber(bool addToList, bool updateAttribute, int listID, ETApplication.Jobs.TriggeredSendSubscriberRequest subscriberRequest) method, ErrorID: 458233301</ErrorDescription>
    </SubscriberFailures>
  </Results>
  <RequestID>4cffe723-68e9-442f-850e-919acff63fb5</RequestID>
  <OverallStatus>Error</OverallStatus>
</CreateResponse>
```

I have a retry mechanism on error and the same request is sent again and this time it succeeds.

I get the following response:

```
ID: 13544
Response-Code: 200
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Headers: {Cache-Control=[private, max-age=0], connection=[close], Content-Length=[1354], content-type=[text/xml; charset=utf-8], Date=[Mon, 08 Aug 2016 00:51:23 GMT], Server=[Microsoft-IIS/7.5], X-AspNet-Version=[4.0.30319], X-Powered-By=[ASP.NET]}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<soap:Header>
<wsa:Action>CreateResponse</wsa:Action>
<wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:595eee6a-50b2-4acb-834d-e469bb5ac15a</wsa:MessageID>
<wsa:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:e306a7ff-d653-4631-94c4-6a92219dfee4</wsa:RelatesTo>
<wsa:To>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:To>
<wsse:Security>
  <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-95b28ea8-da56-42f4-89c9-8e3c27a0c89b">
    <wsu:Created>2016-08-08T00:51:24Z</wsu:Created>
    <wsu:Expires>2016-08-08T00:56:24Z</wsu:Expires>
  </wsu:Timestamp>
</wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
<CreateResponse xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
  <Results xsi:type="TriggeredSendCreateResult">
    <StatusCode>OK</StatusCode>
    <StatusMessage>Created TriggeredSend</StatusMessage>
    <OrdinalID>0</OrdinalID>
    <NewID>0</NewID>
  </Results>
  <RequestID>51f2e998-e6fe-4e93-ac46-d0bdb23328c7</RequestID>
  <OverallStatus>OK</OverallStatus>
</CreateResponse>
```

The request being sent in both cases is:

```
ID: 13543
Address: https://webservice.exacttarget.com/Service.asmx
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], SOAPAction=["Create"]}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
<fueloauth>1agCJw6UxgHrT4bTd5YMruya</fueloauth>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
<CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI" xmlns:ns2="urn:fault.partner.exacttarget.com">
  <Options/>
  <Objects xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="TriggeredSend">
    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
    <ModifiedDate xsi:nil="true"/>
    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
    <TriggeredSendDefinition>
      <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ModifiedDate xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
      <CustomerKey>registration_reward_trigger_prod</CustomerKey>
    </TriggeredSendDefinition>
    <Subscribers>
      <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ModifiedDate xsi:nil="true"/>
      <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
      <EmailAddress>xxxxxxxx@hotmail.com</EmailAddress>
      <Attributes>
        <Name>restaurantAddress1</Name>
        <Value>333 Ontario Street</Value>
      </Attributes>
      <Attributes>
        <Name>OLOSignupRewardExpiryDate</Name>
        <Value>2017-02-07</Value>
      </Attributes>
      <Attributes>
        <Name>signupRewardExpiryDate</Name>
        <Value>2016-08-22</Value>
      </Attributes>
      <Attributes>
        <Name>restaurantCity</Name>
        <Value>St Catharines</Value>
      </Attributes>
      <Attributes>
        <Name>restaurantPhone</Name>
        <Value>(000) 000-0000</Value>
      </Attributes>
      <Attributes>
        <Name>subscriberKey</Name>
        <Value>0bc572dd-35bd-4952-9787-f3067d3e11d0</Value>
      </Attributes>
      <Attributes>
        <Name>recipientEmail</Name>
        <Value>xxxxxxxx@hotmail.com</Value>
      </Attributes>
      <Attributes>
        <Name>firstName</Name>
        <Value>Philip</Value>
      </Attributes>
      <Attributes>
        <Name>externalId</Name>
        <Value>registration_reward_trigger_prod</Value>
      </Attributes>
      <Attributes>
        <Name>restaurantName</Name>
        <Value>St Catharines</Value>
      </Attributes>
      <Attributes>
        <Name>restaurantProvince</Name>
        <Value>ON</Value>
      </Attributes>
      <SubscriberKey>0bc572dd-35bd-4952-9787-f3067d3e11d0</SubscriberKey>
      <Status>Active</Status>
    </Subscribers>
  </Objects>
</CreateRequest>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The ID for the 2nd request is 13544.  That's the only difference.
I am using java and fuel sdk to build the requests.  This error does not always happen, some rquests are successful on the first try.
Any idea why the first request fails?